# Simple Texture Mapping for a generic triangle mesh

Tags: opengl, 3d, textures, polygon, uv-mapping

Suppose that we have a triangle mesh without information about normals and texture coordinates.
(Basically an OBJ file with only vertices and face elements).

The objective is to show something decent using Opengl with a  program written in C.
To calculate the normals of every triangle is easy...

But what about texture mapping?
Can anyone recommend me a simple algorithm/documentation/resource to map the normalized UV coordinates of an image to a generic mesh of triangles?

```
(For a mesh with a single triangle it is easy, ex:  [0][0], [1][0], [0][1])
```

The result doesn't have to be perfect, even professional softwares can't do that without UV unwrapping and UV seams.

Answer (score 1):

The only algorithm I know is for **2D** screen coordinates (screen space):

I already answered a question similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68664209/13151323), focus on the algorithm (ie.,  `texturePos = (vPos - 0.5) * 2`) of conversion between `textureCoords` and `2D vertices`

**EDIT**:

Note; The following is a theory:

There might be a method with **3D** space. Eventually the transformations lead to the vertices being rendered in **2D** screen coordinates.

`local space` --> `world space` --> `view space` --> `NDC space` --> `screen coordinates`

Using the general convention above and the 3 matrices (`Model`, `View`, `Projection`),

and since the vertices will end up in **2D** space, you could create some form of algorithm to back track the textureCoordinates using the inverse Matrices back to **3D** space and move on from there.

This, btw, still is not a defined and perfect algorithm (*maybe there is and someone will edit and add the algorithm here in the future...*)

Comment: You could have written that in a comment... If I asked the question and didn't add any resources, it's just because I can't find anything.

Comment: Asking for a general algorithm will be very hard to find, because algorithm are suited to a certain context or situation, they may not be applicable universally, sometimes even to other problems related closely but not 100%. Anyways I going try my best and edit the question to give you a more detailed answer

Comment: One of the key reasons `textureCoordinates` do not have a algorithm is because they do not relate to the `vertices` or `normals` **closely** (not enough info to be derived) whereas the `normals` are a per-vertex or per-triangle basis (if the a triangle made of three vertices, was considered a plane, you could use basic vector math to calculate the normals).